# TinyMCE right click paste workaround / hack?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, clipboard, paste

At this point, there is no question that right click pasting in TinyMCE is not possible due to browser restrictions (unless the user specifically enables it).

However, is there ANY work around for this, like catching a paste event using JavaScript, pasting the clipboard contents to some hidden textarea somewhere, and then pulling the contents of that and inserting it into wherever they clicked paste? Or is this wishful thinking?

Or would you possible be able to do a `preventdefault` on the right click even so that the normal right click menu comes up instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you want right click pasting, you need to choose between having the TinyMCE contextmenu or right click paste. By disabling contextmenu, the usual browser right click box appears instead, which allows you to paste what's on your clipboard into the rich text box.

Comment: The browser's menu in Chrome doesn't show a Paste option when right clicking. It shows back etc but not paste

Comment: Which version are you using? Do you have a demo by which the issue can be reproduced? Which element are you right clicking? If it's an `input` or `textarea` and the contextmenu is disabled, I can't see any reason why there wouldn't be a paste option, provided that you have something in your clipboard...